# Firebase AppCheck failed to install using NativeScript

Tags: firebase, nativescript, firebase-app-check

I am trying the install `pod 'FirebaseAppCheck', '8.0.0-beta'` in the Podfile of my NativeScript project using target iOS 14.4. However, it gives an error below

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "FirebaseAppCheck":   In Podfile:
> FirebaseAppCheck (= 8.0.0-beta)
>
> Specs satisfying the `FirebaseAppCheck (= 8.0.0-beta)` dependency were
> found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target. 'pod
> install' command failed.

Is this a bug in Firebase AppCheck which requires a future iOS version, or is this an issue with NativeScript that cannot install a beta pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the root cause of this issue and there are 2 parts:

(1) In App_Resources/iOS/Podfile, add `platform :ios, '11.0'` This is for Cocoapods

(2) in App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfigh, add `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0`, this is for XCode

The app should work even after (1) is done. However, in order to be consistent with the target build, I recommend to change both.

However, in my case, I have one more issue after fixing the 2 points above. Because AppCheck requires requires 'Firebase/Core', '~>8.0', but on the other hand, I also have @nativescript/firebase in my project, which hardcodes to use Firebase/Core ~>6.34.0. Therefore, I still cannot make the project working with AppCheck without sacrificing @nativescript/firebase.

Comment: Great to hear you got this working!    If you haven't done so yet, it might be worth also posting an issue on Eddy's repo to ensure the plugin gets updated to the latest SDK version too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @FrankvanPuffelen. Will do!

Comment: It's logged https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/1822